# exibir var Javascript em div html

Tags: javascript, html

O código

```
<section class="content">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/purl.js"></script>
    <script>
        var vars = geturlvar()['Nome'];//traz embalagem.html se colocar um alert!
    </script>

    <img src="../images/aguarde.gif" id="image">
    <div id="url" w3-include-html=vars></div>       

</section>
```

preciso pegar o valor que esta em vars(que é embalagem.html) e colocar dentro da 
`<div id="url" w3-include-html=vars></div>`

como faço isso?

Comment: use: document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = vars;

Comment: coloquei esse codigo abaixo de  var vars = geturlvar()['Nome'] dentro da tag <script>, porem aparece o seguinte erro ao debugar: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null, porem se coloco um alert ou no console recebo o valor da variavel vars ok.

Comment: você está usando ele antes da div ser criada. Coloque seu código javascript depois da criação da div id="url" ou crie um escopo de função em javascript q espera o carregamento da página para depois carregar o javascript

Comment: mas se eu criar o javascript depois da div ele da erro na variavel vars que nao foi definida, vc poderia fazer um exemplo, desculpe sou novo em javascript

Comment: Abaixo tem dois exemplos que resolvem seu problema. Um dado pelo @Artur e outro por mim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda, porem resolvi trocando o método de incluir a pagina embalagens.html dentro de container.html por:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/purl.js"></script>
<script>
    var vars = geturlvar()['Nome'];
    $(function () {
        $("#includedContent").load(vars);
    });
</script>
```

e no body ficou:

```
 <div id="includedContent"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você está tentando colocar o valor na div antes que ela seja criada. Basta colocar seu código dentro de `window.onload`, para que ele execute depois que a tela seja carregada

```js
window.onload = function () {
   var vars = "url_de_teste";
   document.getElementById('url').innerHTML = vars;
}
```

```html
<div id="url"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Tente assim:**

```
<section class="content">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/purl.js"></script>


    <img src="../images/aguarde.gif" id="image">
    <div id="url" w3-include-html=vars></div>     

    <script>
        var vars = geturlvar()['Nome'];
        document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = vars;
    </script>  

</section>
```

Comment: ele retorna undefined e o link que era pra ficar http://localhost/take/pages/embalagem.html, fica http://localhost/take/pages/vars

Comment: O seu geturlvar()['Nome'] está trazendo algum valor?

Comment: tinha esquecido de passar os parametros na URL, ele trouxe, porem, apenas deu print na tela o texto `embalagem.html`, como faço pra ele incluir o w3-include-html, porque ele faz o include da pagina embalagens.html dentro da container.html

Comment: so lembrando que o w3.includeHTML 'e um javascript que faz o include

Comment: O seu w3-include-html=vars faz o include do que dentro da div id="url"?

Comment: isso, se coloco assim funciona:   <div id="url" w3-include-html="embalagens.html"></div>